# ctypes showing incorrect byte size

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import sys



class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a",c_uint64),
        ("b",c_uint64),
        ("c",c_uint64),
        ("d",c_uint64),
        ("e",c_uint64),
        ("f",c_uint64),
        ("g",c_uint64),
        ("h",c_uint64),
        ("i",c_uint64),
        ("j",c_uint64),
        ("k",c_uint64),
        ("l",c_uint64),
        ("m",c_uint64),
        ("n",c_uint64),
        ("o",c_uint64),
        ("p",c_uint64),
        ("q",c_uint64),
        ("r",c_uint64*16),
        ("s",c_uint64*16),
        ("t",c_uint64*16),
        ("u",c_uint64*16),
        ("v",c_uint64*16),
        ("w",c_uint64),
        ("x",c_uint64),
        ("y",c_uint64),
        ("z",c_uint64)
        ]

class B(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a1",c_uint64),
                ("b1",c_uint64),
                ("c1",c_uint64)
           ]

class C(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a2",c_uint64*32),
                ("b2",c_uint64*32),
                ("c2",c_uint64)
               ]


class U_union(Union):
    _fields_ = [("a3", A),
        ("b3",B),
        ("c3",C),
        ("d3",c_uint32),
        ("e3",c_uint32)
        ]


class ether_header(Structure):
   _fields_ = [("ether_dhost", c_uint8*6),
           ("ether_shost", c_uint8*6),
           ("ether_type", c_uint16)
          ]

class D(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("ether",ether_header),
         ("a4", c_uint8),
                 ("b4", c_uint8),
                 ("c4", c_uint8),
                 ("d4", c_uint8),
                 ("e4", c_uint16),
                 ("f4",U_union),
        ]


class Send:
    def __init__(self,a):
        file=D()
        print sizeof(file)

if __name__== "__main__":
    Send("hello")
```

I have to send 830  byte structure.Here dual padding(2bytes at each) is taking place.
This is my sample code,ETHER_HEAD structure is 14 bytes,FILE_HEAD without ether_head structure member is 816 bytes and with ether_head member as 832 bytes.How come 2 bytes got added ?
And i am trying other scenerio like to send only 830 bytes like concatenating 2 structures seperately ,but if i create two object reference for two classes and making + operator in between the objets it showing cannot concat the objects error .how can i simulate it ?

Comment: C structures may contain padding in order to align members correctly.

Comment: @IIka Everila yeah padding bytes are getting added,can we send as seperate structures means like ETHER_HEAD+FILE_HEAD?

Comment: You could just convert each member of each struct for the wire separately and send one after the other. That has the added benefit of not relying on the machine's endianness etc.